# read a 2d array from file-Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Edit: I've solved this. I was not properly reading in the second number at the top of the file so I was getting a square array. I solved it by skipping the first number with a scanner.next(). I'll post the corrected code below. Thanks for everyone's help.

I'm trying to learn file i/o and the project has you read a file you create. The file begins with two numbers that are the number of students in a class and the number of projects to be graded and then after that there is a large matrix beginning with names and then scores to be averaged. Something like this:

2 3

John 44.4 55 66.1

Lisa 33 44 55

The completely corrected method (though still needs fine-tuning for exception handling):

```
public static double[][] getArrays(String fileName, int num1, int num2) {
    double[][] twoDArray = new double[num1][num2];
    String[] names = new String[num1];
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); //Create a scanner               
        fileReader.nextLine();
         do {
            for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
                names[i] = fileReader.next();
                System.out.println(names[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[0].length; j++) {
                    twoDArray[i][j] = fileReader.nextDouble();
                }
                fileReader.nextLine();
            }
        } while (fileReader.hasNext());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchElementException ex) { //Catch any exceptions
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
    return twoDArray;
}// end of get2DArray method
```

Comment: is your project requiring the use of a 2d array?

Comment: Yes you are right. It is because of the presence of string. You traverse through it by calling fileReader.next();

Comment: @mig Yeah, it says you're supposed to use a 2D array along with any other arrays that are necessary.

Comment: @Sourabh I experimented with the placing of the fileReader.next() but I'm still getting zeroes. Am I supposed to use more than one?

Comment: @user3397166 i put my example below

Comment: It is because the hasNextDouble() returns false as there is no double value (there is a name) and the program never enters any loop.

Comment: @Sourabh Thanks, I see that now. I have it looping mostly correct now, I'm getting the names as one array and the scores as another (2D) array. But for some reason the scores are represented as groups of three decimals instead of doubles, and also I'm not getting the last two columns of the scores. Any idea what I'm doing wrong now? I've updated my code.

Comment: I have put a code below. Try to understand it before you use.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is titled,

> read a 2d array from file-Java

But I think that the last thing you want to do here is to create a 2D array, and your code is completely ignoring the student's name.

Instead you should create a Student class, one that has two fields, a String field to hold the student's name, and an `ArrayList<Double>` or `double[]`, your choice, to hold the grades.

Then put each Student object, which you create on reading in a line of data from the file, into either an `ArrayList<Student>` or a `Student[]` array, again your choice.

If you go with arrays (which I'm guessing is your requirement for your class), then pseudo code could be:

```
create File Scanner object, fileScanner
read line, 
create line Scanner with line, 
get both ints studentCount and gradeCount, and store in variables.
dispose of line Scanner
Create Student array
??? possibly read an empty line (if your file representation is accurate). 
for index goes from 0 to < student count
  read line with File Scanner
  create line Scanner with line
  next token goes into a name String
  create 1-D double array
  for other index goes from 0 to < gradeCount
    use line scanner to get doubles and put into one double array
  end for loop
  dispose of line scanner
  create Student object with name and double array, 
  place Student object into Student array
end for loop
dispose of file scanner
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe from looking at your code that you are never actually putting values into the array and due to the fact that when you a print an initialized array that has never had any values associated it will automatically print `0.0`

What is causing you not to put any values in the array is your `while(fileReader.hasNextDouble())`  this is searching for a double next but a string is located there so your while loop isn't happening. (For future reference in debugging adding a simple `System.out.println("Hit");` inside your while loop will tell you if you are getting there). There are a couple of changes based on the structure of your txt file that I would do and i have put the code below.

```
while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num1FromFile; i++) {
        fileReader.next();
        for (int j = 0; j < num2FromFile; j++) {
            twoDArray[i][j] = fileReader.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I appreciate the help! This certainly works better, but now it gives me only one double which is the second to last double in the row of number I've entered in the file. Any idea what would work around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[][] getArrays(String fileName) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    int numNames = scanFile.nextInt();
    int numScores = scanFile.nextInt();
    double[][] scores = new double[numNames][numScores];
    String[] names = new String[numNames];

    for(int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        names[i] = scanFile.next();
        for(int j = 0; j < numScores; j++) {
            scores[i][j] = scanFile.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    scanFile.close();
    return scores;
}
```

Try to understand the logic before you use it. There might be typo errors in the code above as I am directly typing it in here. The `names` are read into an array but not used. I believe you are not interested in names, as your method is only returning `double[][]`. Also I am assuming that the file is perfect, without any comments etc.